# Proper CMakeLists

Tags: ros-melodic, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like I do not understand something in CMakelists. In my package, I have two C++ files, one called uart.cpp and another one called joint.cpp.

Joint uses uart functions and variables but only Join has rosnode and main function, so how do I make my CMakelists? I get that uart functions have undefined references and my CMakelists:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(genius_control)

add_compile_options(-std=c++11)


find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
        roscpp
        serial
)

catkin_package(
   INCLUDE_DIRS
        include
   CATKIN_DEPENDS
        roscpp
   LIBRARIES
        genius_control
)


include_directories(
  include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
        DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
        FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h"
        PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE)

add_library(genius_control
        include/${PROJECT_NAME}/uart.h
        include/${PROJECT_NAME}/joint.h
        src/uart.cpp
        src/joint.cpp
        )

add_executable(joint src/joint.cpp)

target_link_libraries(genius_control ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/320316/proper-cmakelists/) by [EdwardNur](https://answers.ros.org/users/39496/edwardnur/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2019-04-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-04-04**:
Please note: this is not a Catkin or ROS related question. It's purely CMake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should change the `add_executable` to
`add_executable(joint src/joint.cpp src/uart.cpp)` otherwise it cannot locate the implementation of the functions that the `uart.cpp` file includes.
As for the `add_library`, it can include only the header files and not the *.cpp.
As for the `target_link_libraries(genius_control ${catkin_LIBRARIES})`, you should change it to `target_link_libraries(joint ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

**edit:** The previous is a working, but not really proper way to solve this, as far as I know. A better way would be the following:

```
[..previous are ok]

catkin_package(
   INCLUDE_DIRS
        include
   CATKIN_DEPENDS
        roscpp
   LIBRARIES
        genius_control  
        uart
)

include_directories(
  include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
        DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
        FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h"
        PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE)

add_library(uart  
     src/uart.cpp  
)  
target_link_libraries(uart
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)

add_executable(joint    
     src/joint.cpp
)  
target_link_libraries(joint   
    ${catkin_LIBRARIES}  
    uart  
)
```

---

Originally posted by [kosmastsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/36854/kosmastsk/) with karma: 210 on 2019-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [EdwardNur](https://answers.ros.org/users/39496/edwardnur/) on 2019-04-04**:
I am getting this error

```
CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target: genius_control
CMake Error: Cannot determine link language for target "genius_control".
```

**Comment by [kosmastsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/36854/kosmastsk/) on 2019-04-04**:
I edited my answer, check if this works